# Get all Items of a custom ArrayAdapter in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-arrayadapter

I'm making a custom ArrayAdapter and I need to get the Items List, I simply create a method named getItems that return the list passed in the adapter constructor, the problem is that Android studio gives me this error message:
[image: Android studio problem]

I have do this in Java, but in Kotlin can achieve the same behaviour.
This is mi actual code:

```
class FichaDeContactoVaciaAdapter(context: Context,var items : 
List<FichaContacto>) : ArrayAdapter<FichaContacto>(context, 0, items){

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    val rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_ficha_contacto, parent,false)


    val addCardButton = rowView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.anadirFichaButton)
    addCardButton.setOnClickListener{

        add(FichaContacto())
    }

    val currentFichaContacto = getItem(position)

   // rowView.textInputLayoutficha.setText("Hola mundo desde el adapter")

    val removeCardText = rowView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.removerFicha)

    if (count == 1){
        removeCardText.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    removeCardText.setOnClickListener{
        Toast.makeText(rowView.context,"Estás haciendo click en el label " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        if(count > 1){
            remove(getItem(position))
        }
    }

    return rowView


}

fun getItems(): List<FichaContacto> {
    return items
}
```

}

So, How can I get the Items list of a ArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete `getItems()` function. And you can access items property
like this.

```
val adapter = FichaDeContactoVaciaAdapter(context, items)
adapter.items
```